# Why can't I call seq functions in a sequence generated by js->clj?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Although I can get turn a simple js object into a clojure object with something like;

```
(-> "{a: 2, b: 3}" js* js->clj)
```

I'm apparently not being able to do so with a particular object, `goog.events.BrowserEvent`, in a handler function like:

```
(defn handle-click [e]
  ...
  (-> e .-evt js->clj keys) ;; <-------------
  ...
```

The function does get applied, but the resulting object doesn't respond to sequence functions like `count`or `first`, although I can fetch items using `aget`. The error message I get, in chrome's console, is;

```
Uncaught Error: No protocol
method ISeqable.-seq defined for type object: [object Object]
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't `js->clj` work with all objects?

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `js->clj` only changes something that is exactly a JavaScript object (it is implemented using `instance?` instead of `isa?`, and with good reasons), when you pass a descendant of `js\Object` `js->clj` returns the same object. `aget` (and `aset`) works because it compiles down to the `object[field-name]` syntax on JavaScript.

You can extend the `ISeq` protocol (or any other protocol) to the `goog.events.BrowserEvent` and all functions that works with `ISeq` will work with `goog.events.BrowserEvent`. There is a [talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5edtbpVOOBI) by Chris Houser where he showed how to extend a bunch of protocols to a goog Map. I recommend watching the whole talk, but the part that are relevant to your question begins at approximately 14 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

First, I found out functions in google closure to get the keys and values of an object:

```
 (defn goog-hash-map [object]
   (zipmap (goog.object/getKeys object) (goog.object/getValues object)))
```

Then, by studying the source of cljs.core, I realized all I had to do was to extend the IEncodeClojure interface with it:

```
 (extend-protocol IEncodeClojure
   goog.events.BrowserEvent
   (-js->clj
    ([x {:keys [keywordize-keys] :as options}]
       (let [keyfn (if keywordize-keys keyword str)]
         (zipmap (map keyfn (gobj/getKeys x)) (gobj/getValues x))))
    ([x] (-js->cljs x {:keywordize-keys false}))))
```

The [original code](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/cljs/cljs/core.cljs) doesn't work on this object, because its type must be exactly Object. I tried to change the comparison function to instance?, ie,

```
(instance? x js/Object) (into {} (for [k (js-keys x)]
                                      [(keyfn k) (thisfn (aget x k))]))
```

but that didn't work either, wielding the following error, which made me settle for the previous approach.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, 
but got function Object() { [native code] }`.
```

Comment: `(instance? x js/Object)` doesn't work because the first parameter to `instance?` should be a class. You should use `(isa? x js/Object)` instead.